# jQuery and ajax to update rows in MySQL while in jQueryUI dialogbox widget

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

Okay, before anyone blasts me into space with this question (I've read the questions with similar titles prior), here's where I'm at.

I've heavily integrated jQueryUI into my web application and one of the widgets I use is the dialogbox. User clicks a button (selector) and it pops out a list of his friends. Beside every friend is a **DELETE** button which goes:

```
<form method="post" action="togglefriend.php">
 <input type="hidden" value="<?=$uid;?>" name="uid" />
 <input type="hidden" value="<?=$fid;?>" name="fid" />
 <input type="hidden" value="action" name="delete" />
 <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

`togglefriend.php` does the updating **after sanitation** with:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE friends SET isapproved='0' WHERE uid='$uid' AND fid='$fid'");
```

This method, of course, exits the dialogbox widget and shows the user results from togglefriend.php (or the page it redirects to). **I like the idea of the user not having to exit the dialogbox widget so they could delete as many friends as they want.** It will have to update the MySQL database, at the same time remove the entire `<tr></tr>` of that specific friend from div the dialogbox is showing from.

I know a little about jQuery's `ajax()` and `post()` methods (I use `post()` and `load()` to get the contents of the dialogbox) but just couldn't think of a workaround on this one. If anyone could probably provide examples or point me to the direction where I could learn the easiest (the docs I've read are just too much for a newbie like me) - it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Im a little confused on what the part that you're getting hung up is.  How to remove the TR from the div?  You can just add an id tag to the tr's based on your uid, and modify the table based on the TR ID that way.   If that's not the issue please let us know!  Thanks

Comment: When the Delete button is clicked beside a user, I'd like for it to perform an ajax action (update the sql database and remove the table row). This is where I'm actually lost. No knowledge on how to do it to be specific. Because what I'm doing right now is sending the POST data to another page with exits the dialogbox widget.

Comment: if you want it to be clicked, why not put an `onclick` event? that fires a function. inside the function is an ajax call to your `php` that does the CRUD (deleting)?

Comment: @ianace That's exactly what I want it to do. Just 0% clue on how.

Comment: a question though, how did you generate the list?

Comment: @ianace - extract($row,EXTR_PREFIX_ALL,"f") from an sql query wrapped in a while statement.

Comment: did you generate it through ajax?

Comment: @ianace - Nope. This will be the first time I'm using ajax via jQuery.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7179/discussion-between-ianace-and-mike-sanchez)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'togglefriend.php',
  data: 'uid=888&fid=999',
  success: function() {
      $('#friend-999').hide();  //assuming you give each <tr> a unique ID.
    });
});
```